# One of the fragments can’t immediately update data from other fragments

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-viewpager

There’s fragment that have four tabs on top.
Every tab has own fragment.
I use first, second, third tab’s fragment to collect data save at my SharedPreferences
And in fourth tab to receive it.

When switching fourth page,I would like to see the information I choose from others fragment.
My  problem is Only first tab can immediately pass data to fourth page,
Whatever I save anything, it can display at fourth page right away that’s what I want.

However,
Others are weird

I need to one more step to switch to first’s tab , it can even update my data from other tabs to fourth page.

What did I wrong with my code or order make this happen ?

```
public class UserActivityMenuFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String[] sTitle = new String[]{"first","second","third","fourth"};


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_activity,container ,false);
    initView(view);
    return view;
}


private void initView(View view) {
    ViewPager mViewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.containerView);
    TabLayout mTabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText(sTitle[0]));
    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText(sTitle[1]));
    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText(sTitle[2]));
    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText(sTitle[3]));


    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    fragments.add(FirstFragment.newInstance());
    fragments.add(SecondFragment.newInstance());
    fragments.add(ThirdFragment.newInstance());
    fragments.add(FourthFragment.newInstance());


    UserActivityMenuAdapter adapter = new UserActivityMenuAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),fragments, Arrays.asList(sTitle));
    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);


    mTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

}
```

My adapter

```
public class UserActivityMenuAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> mFragments ;
    private List<String> mTitles ;

    public UserActivityMenuAdapter
            (FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments, List<String> titles) {
        super(fm);
        mFragments = fragments;
        mTitles = titles;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments == null ?0:mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mTitles.get(position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FragmentStatePagerAdapter do not save any Fragment instances but their savedInstanceState.

if a Fragment(page) is not visible, its instance will remain destroyed until it is visible again,then will be recreated from savedInstanceState.

if you want to keep all Fragments alive,use FragmentPagerAdapter instead of FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

see 
[Offical doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter)

Answer (score 0):

The `ViewPager` doesn’t create all its pages at once. You can use below snippet to force it maintain all your fragments at the same time:

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
```